# What is a swamp cooler?

Tags: fermentation-temperature, fermentation, equipment, techniques

What type of equipment do you need to build one?
How do you use it?
What are the realistic expectations of using one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of brewing, I have seen folks keeping things cool by putting the carboy into a larger sized bucket of water, swap out ice or ice packs daily or more often if you live in a very hot place, and drape a wet towel around the shoulder of the carboy.  For added cooling, you could point a fan at this whole setup.

I had a friend do this in his basement to brew a lager.  It worked surprisingly well.

Comment: What time of year did he do it for a lager?  I've done the swamp cooler thing for ales a lot in the summer months.  But now I wonder if you could lager with one in the late fall and spring.  Interesting.

Comment: I brewed a Vienna Lager this spring using the swamp cooler/daily ice packs in my basement (which I think was around 50-55, not sure though) and it turned out very good.

Comment: @Brewchez:
My buddy did it in late fall/early winter.  He put it in his mostly underground basement, and filled it twice a day with ice and water.  Not sure if this is important or not, but he did use better bottles instead of a glass carboy.